# .NET Windows Forms Anatomy

Tags: .net, winforms

Can anybody help me understand the anatomy of a Windows Form (.net)?

When I create a new Windows Form from my .NET application, I can see in the designer class some basic amount of code generated by the studio. I have just copy pasted it below.

```
namespace FormBasic
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(292, 266);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Of them what I found interesting was this line of code

```
private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
```

What exactly is this Container? 
I debugged by placing a break point in the `InitializeComponent` function. The `components` remain null.

Also the hierarchy of the Form class is Form class Inherits from `ContainerControl` class. Can you please help me to clear these terminologies?

Comment: Drop a control onto the page, run debug again and see what happens :)

Comment: I did that. Minor tweaks happen in the designer code to accommodate the newly added control. But still the components remain null.

Comment: Are you asking because you want to be able to do something in particular, or are you just curious about how the designer code works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `components` field is a container for non-visual components (like `OpenFileDialog`, `ErrorProvider`, `FileSystemWatcher`...). It's only initialized if you have such components on your form. It's a way to ensure that these components are disposed when the form is disposed.

Comment: Ok. that was the catch. NON-VISUAL!!!! Thanks. But is there anything more you can add or provide a link for me to understand more about windows forms.

Comment: @Nishant, [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656767.aspx) looks like a good starting point

Answer (score 1):

The line `private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;` facilitates the management of items like `Timer` or `BackgroundWorker` in the "Components" section of the toolbox. In the editor, they show up like this:

[image]